# console.log(document) through content script returns html elements in content script console a bit different than inspect page console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

console.log(document) through content script returns **html** elements in content script console a bit different than inspect page console

suppose i am developing content script for a web page and when i inspect the page using chrome i get following elements

```
  <button id="btn">click me<button/>
  <input id="prc" value=8181/>
```

and when i check this html document through my content script just using following code :

console.log(document)

then i am not getting all the elements in the console :

```
  <button id="btn">click me<button/>
```

(**probably missing input element or some others)**

I've tried many solutions regarding page loading but nothing is working.

here's `manifest.json` :

```
{
    "name": "Sarkar Communication Stocks Updater",
    "description" : "This extension asks sarkarians to decide whether certain parts are physically consumed or not while call closing",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons" : { "128" : "SC_logo_128.png"},

    "permissions" : [
        "http://sapgwprd.lavapartners.in:8000/*",
        "tabs"
    ],

    "browser_action" : {
        "defaul_title" : "Sarkar Communication Stock Updater",
        "icons"  : 
        {
            "128" : "SC_logo_128.png",
            "16"  : "SC_logo_16.png"
        }
     },


     "content_scripts" : [
         {
             "matches" : [
                "http://sapgwprd.lavapartners.in:8000/*"
             ],
             "js" : ["content.js"],
             "run_at" : "document_end"
         }
     ]
}
```

Comment: The question should contain the actual code that uses console.log. Without it I can only guess it's [console.log() inconsistency with objects and arrays](//stackoverflow.com/a/42275334)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. edited the question